# Unable to install Intel® HAXM Please file a bug against Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to install the intel haxm but it givin the error. Please I  request you that please let me know about it.

Comment: detailed; Can you give information. eg: Output, Image , Log

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install HAXM from Android Studio?

Try to install from Intel Github Link Given below

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases